# Remove scsslint_tmp files generating automatically?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jslint, jshint

I am using WebStorm with JSLint, JSHint and some files are generating automatically in the same source directory with `filename_scsslint_tmpXXXXXXX`.

Can anyone please tell me how can remove this functionality and what is the use of it?

Comment: I have the same issue with RubyMine and ESlint, I don't use scss or css for anything, I'm working on a React Native project.

Answer (score 2):

Please submit this to [scss-lint-plugin](https://github.com/idok/scss-lint-plugin) vendor, https://github.com/idok/scss-lint-plugin/issues.
see also https://github.com/idok/scss-lint-plugin/issues/45